# Facebook Graph API - difference between 'location' and 'place'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is the difference between the `location` and `place` properties of a node?

With this query: `me/albums?fields=id, description, location, created_time`, I can get:

```
"location": "Paris, France"
```

But with this query: `me/photos/uploaded?fields=id, album.fields(id), name, created_time, location`, I get:

```
"location": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "---", 
        "from": {
          "id": "---", 
          "name": "--"
        }, 
        "type": "photo", 
        "place": {
          "id": "----", 
          "name": "Paris", 
          "location": {
            "city": "Paris", 
            "country": "France", 
            "latitude": 48.871082594985, 
            "longitude": 2.3349405651766, 
            "street": "Paris", 
            "zip": "Paris"
          }
        }, 
        "application": {
          "name": "Photos", 
          "id": "----"
        }, 
        "created_time": "2014-04-22T15:39:48+0000"
      }
    ]
  }
```

In the latter, if I replace location with `place`, I don't get any results for place but don't get an error either....

On the other hand, this query: `me/albums?fields=id, description, place, created_time`, gives me:

```
"place": {
    "id": "---", 
    "name": "Paris, France", 
    "location": {
      "latitude": 48.8567, 
      "longitude": 2.3508
    }
  }
```

Previously, a location node would contain a place. But not place contains location and if I'm doing object oriented design, this is a problem.

This seems very inconsistent. I know that I'm querying two different nodes (albums and photos) but the mix-up between place and location exists with both of them. I only want to get information about the place that's being tagged, like name, city, country, ...
Bottom line I want to get all the locations that the user has ever inputted for anything and I'm going node-by-node (also because I need the content of the nodes).

Also, the location property doesn't allow subfields. So doing location.fields(...) isn't an option. It's curious why I get a 'data' node under location.